# visual studio 2010 last successful build

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I made some changes to my website, then had to reformat my server, and over two weeks I tried to undo what I did (it was a stupid forum thingy). Obviously I missed something, becuase now I have the dreaded Build Failed With No Error problem.

This is my home server, so no I am not running source control.

After staring at it for a few days, I decided to try somehting. Today I allowed VS to run the last successful build, and it still works.

QUESTION: How can I go back to the last successful build? I don't care about any changes made since it worked. That's really all I need.

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to see if you have [Previous Versions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions) available?

It sounds like you won't likely be able to recover the source files / project config, though you could certainly attempt to recover the "source" by using tools like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) or [.NET Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/). You can use them to examine the output assemblies, and reconstruct your code if necessary.

As a lesson learned, both [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) and [Git](http://git-scm.com/) work wonderfully for versioning home projects - I'd give a slight nod to Mercurial in your case as it works just a tad bit easier on the Windows platform.